# Not seeing Kinesis connector package in Flink 1.17

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We were using Flink kinesis connector library of flink(1.16) package in our Flink job. Now we are planning to move to Flink 1.17 but I am seeing flink-kinesis-connector package got removed from Flink-1.17. Our Flink job was referring multiple classes of flink-kinesis-connector package. Can anybody please tell me what is the alternative implementation of flink-kinesis-connector package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Flink connectors have been externalized since Flink 1.17, which is probably why you don't see them directly. The connectors are still there, just have a different version number, as you can see in the documentation page for the Flink Kinesis connector at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/ - At the time of writing this answer, the latest version is 4.1.0-1.17

Comment: Thanks @martijn-visser. I tried adding flink-connector 4.1.0-1.17 dependency but started getting this new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77034893/facing-sequencenumber-is-treated-as-a-generic-type-exception-with-flink-connecto

Comment: @martin-visser, any idea on how can i fix this issue?

Comment: I've replied in the other S.O. post